# Linear system of ODEs problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this system of ODEs :
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{x}'= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\-\frac{1}{t^2} & \frac{1}{t}\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{x}+ \begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{t^2}\end{pmatrix}\\
\Rightarrow & x_1'=x_2,\\&x_2'=-\frac{1}{t^2}x_1+\frac{1}{t}x_2+\frac{1}{t^2}\\
\end{align}
So I tried to solve this by converting this system into a 2nd order linear ODE. I used 2 approaches,

$1)$ Converting the system into a 2nd order linear ODE in terms of $x_1$, I eventually get$$\mathbf{x}=c_1\binom{t}{1}+c_2\binom{tln|t|}{1+ln|t|}+\binom{1}{0}$$
$2)$ Converting the system into a 2nd order linear ODE in terms of $x_2$, I eventually get$$\mathbf{x}=c_1\binom{tln|t|-t}{ln|t|}+c_2\binom{t}{1}+\binom{1}{0}$$
Everything is the same except for that one term. I thought they could be constant multiple of each other but I could not show that.

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two answers are equivalent:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{x}&=&c_1\binom{t}{1}+c_2\binom{tln|t|}{1+ln|t|}+\binom{1}{0}\\
&=&c_1\binom{t}{1}+c_2\binom{tln|t|}{ln|t|}+c_2\binom{0}{1}+\binom{1}{0}\\
&=&c_1\binom{t}{1}+c_2\binom{tln|t|-t}{ln|t|}+c_2\binom{t}{1}+\binom{1}{0}\\
&=&c_2\binom{tln|t|-t}{ln|t|}+(c_1+c_2)\binom{t}{1}+\binom{1}{0}\\
&=&k_1\binom{tln|t|-t}{ln|t|}+k_2\binom{t}{1}+\binom{1}{0}
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $k_1=c_2$ and $k_2=c_1+c_2$.